# SwiftUI Present Alert with Input Field?

Tags: swift, alert, swiftui, input-field, swift5

In SwiftUI I'm trying to make an alert message with input, and then get the value from the input. I've found many good tutorials how to make the Alert View in SwiftUI, but dont found how to add TextField() in Alert. This alert will update Categories table on Server, i will call a put request with this alert.

```swift
@State var isInsertAlertVisible = false
// state var is define in ContentView
// Button is define in body
Button(action: {
       self.isInsertAlertVisible = true
       }
       ,
       label: {
       Text("Create")
          .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
          .foregroundColor(Color.white)
})
.presentation($isInsertAlertVisible) {
    Alert(title: Text("Insert"), message:
        Text("Insert Categories"), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK!")){
            print("Got it")
    })

}
.padding(.all)
.background(Color.blue)
```

Comment: You're missing some things. First, what does this alert update? What app state (`@State`, `BindableObject`, whatever) is being update? That's what you need to pass to your alert. Second, it looks like you aren't yet using beta 4, because `presentation` is deprecated. It's been out for almost a week now, you probably should download it. Finally, what happens in the case of the user *not* entering something in the `Text` but simply clicking the dismiss button?

Comment: This alert will update Categories table on Server, i will call a put request with this alert.
I think i am not missing state var `@State var isInsertAlertVisible = false` is define in `ContentView` and in `Presentation` i am using this state variable with `($isInsertAlertVisible)`.
I just came to know that `presentation` is deprecated.
Maybe tutorials are not updated according to deprication.

Comment: Beta 4 broke four different things in my app - presentations/alerts being one of them. What I meant by *state* isn't just a flag to use to show what the, um, state of the popup is - but what state the textbook is updating, as in your app model. I have a modal that is used to select something from a list and update a `BindableObject` that is passed as an `@EnvironmentObject` to the modal using the `.environmentObject` modifier. I think it sounds like that's what you're going to need to do.

Comment: Can you update my code or provide an example to achieve this.?

Comment: For those looking for answer on the topic - https://stackoverflow.com/a/61268272/12299030 gives a solution.