# .sheet: Shows only once and then never again

Tags: swiftui

Working with Beta4, it seems that the bug is still existing. The following sequence of views (a list, where a tap on a list entry opens another list) allows to present the `ListView` exactly once; the `onDisappear` is never called, so the `showModal` flag changes, but does not triggers the redisplay of `ListView` when tapped again. So, for each `GridCellBodyEntry`, the `.sheet` presentation works exactly once, and then never again.

I tried around with several suggestions and workarounds, but none worked (e.g., encapsulating with a NavigationViewModel). I even tried to remove the List, because there was an assumption that the `List` causes that behaviour, but even this did not change anything.

Are there any ideas around?

The setup:

1. A `GridCellBody` with this view:

```
var body: some View {

        GeometryReader { geometry in

            VStack {

                List {

                    Section(footer: self.footerView) {

                        ForEach(self.rawEntries) { rawEntry in

                            GridCellBodyEntry(entityType: rawEntry)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .background(Color.white)
            }
        }
    }
```

2. A `GridCellBodyEntry` with this definition:

```
struct GridCellBodyEntry: View {


    let entityType: EntityType
    let viewModel: BaseViewModel


    init(entityType: EntityType) {

        self.entityType = entityType
        self.viewModel = BaseViewModel(entityType: self.entityType)
    }


    @State var showModal = false {

        didSet {

            print("showModal: \(showModal)")
        }
    }


    var body: some View {

        Group {

            Button(action: {

                self.showModal.toggle()
            },
                   label: {

                    Text(entityType.localizedPlural ?? "")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            })
            .sheet(isPresented: $showModal, content: {

                ListView(showModal: self.$showModal,
                         viewModel: self.viewModel)
            })
        }.onAppear{
            print("Profile appeared")
        }.onDisappear{
            print("Profile disappeared")
        }
    }
}
```

3. A `ListView` with this definition:

```
struct ListView: View {


    // MARK: - Private properties


    // MARK: - Public interface


    @Binding var showModal: Bool
    @ObjectBinding var viewModel: BaseViewModel


    // MARK: - Main view


    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {

            VStack {

                List {

                    Section(footer: Text("\(viewModel.list.count) entries")) {

                        ForEach(viewModel.list, id: \.objectID) { item in

                            NavigationLink(destination: ItemView(),
                                           label: {

                                            Text("\(item.objectID)")
                            })
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarItems(leading:

                Button(action: {

                    self.showModal = false
                }, label: {

                    Text("Close")
                }))

            .navigationBarTitle(Text(viewModel.entityType.localizedPlural ?? ""))
        }
    }
}
```

4. The `BaseViewModel` (excerpt):

```
class BaseViewModel: BindableObject {

    /// The binding support. 
    var willChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

    /// The context.
    var context: NSManagedObjectContext

    /// The current list of typed items.
    var list: [NSManagedObject] = []

    // ... other stuff ...
}
```

where `willChange.send()` is called whenever something changes (create, modify, delete operations).

Comment: I've *never* had this issue. Notsaying it isn't happening, but.... A thought. Could you try the following? (1) A very simple project - in fact, I posted a full answer with a repo today that works - anyways, one that simply shows a sheet and dismisses it, repeatedly. (2) Add a simply `List` that doesn't do much, only exhibits master/detail and state update. Then and only then, add in doing a modal sheet. Again, I'm not saying this isn't a bug (and if in fact it is a bug, have you file it with Apple?) I'm merely trying to rule out some things I haven't seen since beta 1.

Comment: Here's a link to my answer, with a link there to a beta 4 project, that uses a model, a sheet with a dismiss button, and is written for beta 4: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57148220/swiftui-present-alert-with-input-field/57163461#57163461

Comment: I took your repo project, and it worked. Then I changed ```VStack``` to ```List```, and it broke. Then I moved ```.sheet``` after ```padding()```(i.e., outside the ```List``` brackets, and it worked again. Put everything in a ```NavigationView```, still working.

Comment: Wrapped the stuff inside the ```List``` into a ```ForEach```, still working. That is really strange, as this is now similar to my current code, which is not working. There is one major difference: While you submit the view model via ```environmentObject```, I hand it over as parameter. Will change that and see if it makes a difference. (Actually, from my understanding, this should not have an impact... but you never know...)

Comment: Well, tried around a bit more: in the master, I took out ```GeometryReader```, ```VStack```, ```Section```- no change. In the detail, I took out ```NavigationView```,  ```VStack```- no change. Before, I change to ```EnvironmentObject``` for handing over the view model -  no change. Very strange...

Comment: When looking into the debug statements, then we see that the flag is toggled correctly. For me it seems that the flag toggling does not trigger a reset of the ```.sheet``` internals, so that a subsequent change to ```true``` leads to an action there.

Answer (score 2):

This is a variant of [swiftUI PresentaionLink does not work second time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57063633/swiftui-presentaionlink-does-not-work-second-time/57087399#57087399)

The following simplified code exhibits the behavior you're experiencing (the sheet only displays once):

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isPresented = false
    @State var whichPresented = -1

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(0 ..< 10) { i in
                    Button(action: {
                            self.whichPresented = i
                            self.isPresented.toggle()
                        })
                        { Text("Button \(i)") }
                    }.sheet(isPresented: $isPresented, content: { 
Text("Destination View \(self.whichPresented)") })
                }
            }
    }
}
```

There appears to be a bug in SwiftUI when you put the `.sheet` inside a List or a ForEach. If you move the `.sheet` outside of the List, you should be able to get the correct behavior.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isPresented = false
    @State var whichPresented = -1

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(0 ..< 10) { i in
                    Button(action: {
                            self.whichPresented = i
                            self.isPresented.toggle()
                        })
                        { Text("Button \(i)") }
                    }
                }
            }.sheet(isPresented: $isPresented, content: { Text("Destination View \(self.whichPresented)") })
    }
}
```

Comment: I reworked my code accordingly, but still have the same effect. I then replaced my code with yours, and it still shows once only.

Comment: This also happens inside of a scrollview