# SwiftUI: UIAlertController's textField does not responding in UIAlertAction

Tags: ios, uikit, swiftui, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

I need to use `UIAlertContoller`, as SwiftUI's `Alert` does not support `TextField`.

I must not use Custom created AlertView, due to various reason(Accessibility, DynamicType, Dark Mode support etc).

**Basic Idea is, SwiftUI's alert must hold `TextField` & entered text must be reflect back for usage.**

I created a SwiftUI `view` by Conforming to `UIViewControllerRepresentable` following is working code.

```
struct AlertControl: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    typealias UIViewControllerType = UIAlertController

    @Binding var textString: String
    @Binding var show: Bool

    var title: String
    var message: String

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<AlertControl>) -> UIAlertController {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)

        alert.addTextField { textField in
            textField.placeholder = "Enter some text"
        }

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "cancel", style: .destructive) { (action) in
            self.show = false
        }

        let submitAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Submit", style: .default) { (action) in
            self.show = false
        }

        alert.addAction(cancelAction)
        alert.addAction(submitAction)

        return alert
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIAlertController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<AlertControl>) {

    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> AlertControl.Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {

        var control: AlertControl

        init(_ control: AlertControl) {
            self.control = control
        }

        func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
            if let text = textField.text {
                self.control.textString = text
            }

            return true
        }
    }
}

// SwiftUI View in some content view
 AlertControl(textString: self.$text,
                             show: self.$showAlert,
                             title: "Title goes here",
                             message: "Message goes here")
```

**Problem:**

There is No activity in Alert Action when it is tapped. I put breakpoints to check, but it never hit there.

Even `UITextFieldDelegate`'s function never hit.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
```

Edit: `cancelAction` or `submitAction` does not triggers on tap of these fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is full demo module for solution that works. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

[image: demo]

See also important comments inline

```
struct AlertControl: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    @Binding var textString: String
    @Binding var show: Bool

    var title: String
    var message: String

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<AlertControl>) -> UIViewController {
        return UIViewController() // holder controller - required to present alert
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<AlertControl>) {
        guard context.coordinator.alert == nil else { return }
        if self.show {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
            context.coordinator.alert = alert

            alert.addTextField { textField in
                textField.placeholder = "Enter some text"
                textField.text = self.textString            // << initial value if any
                textField.delegate = context.coordinator    // << use coordinator as delegate
            }
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "cancel", style: .destructive) { _ in
                // your action here
            })
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Submit", style: .default) { _ in
                // your action here
            })

            DispatchQueue.main.async { // must be async !!
                viewController.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {
                    self.show = false  // hide holder after alert dismiss
                    context.coordinator.alert = nil
                })
            }
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> AlertControl.Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        var alert: UIAlertController?
        var control: AlertControl
        init(_ control: AlertControl) {
            self.control = control
        }

        func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
            if let text = textField.text as NSString? {
                self.control.textString = text.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
            } else {
                self.control.textString = ""
            }
            return true
        }
    }
}

// Demo view for Alert Controll
struct DemoAlertControl: View {
    @State private var text = ""
    @State private var showAlert = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Alert") { self.showAlert = true }
                .background(AlertControl(textString: self.$text, show: self.$showAlert,
                         title: "Title goes here", message: "Message goes here"))
            Text(self.text)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response, but it does not solve actual problem. `cancelAction` or `submitAction` does not trigger, when tap on these button.

Comment: Thanks @Asperi, This is working as expected, but sometime screen freezes & I see following warning in console. 

```2020-04-17 22:11:27.121106+0530 SwiftUI Alert Controller[98884:3206838] Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7f8cdd87e000>  on <UIViewController: 0x7f8cdd704fd0> which is already presenting (null)```

Overall it solved the problem. Thanks again.

Comment: @Nasir, added guard to already shown alert to avoid unintended refresh

Comment: Thanks @Asperi, but I don't see what is purpose of guard statement & alert instance in coordinator, Even with these changes above mentioned warning does appear. It seems that alert controller is presented but it never dismissed. At some place we required to dismiss presented alert. let me know your thoughts, I m working on it, I ll update once I reach any conclusion. BTW thanks for your effort. :)

Comment: @Nasir, what do you mean by "never dismissed"? As I tested & demo'd alert works as expected and dismissed on any button click. Do you use different Xcode version, or conditions? The `guard` is needed, because we do not control when SwiftUI calls update in representable, so to avoid conflict if alert is already shown I added guard and modify code to store alert. As I tested with this approach I do not receive any warnings in console any more.

Comment: I mean ```alert.dismiss(animated: true) {
                    self.show = false
                } ``` in `UIAlertAction`, also you did not see this warning because your code has this statement, `if self.show {`, for some reason I have to remove this condition which causes above warning, Now it is working like charm, Thanks @Asperi

Comment: I tried the solution in iOS15 shouldChangeCharactersIn doesnt get called :(

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to support previous versions, than in iOS16 you actually can use `TextField` in `.alert()` in a very straightforward way.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isShowingAlert = false
    @State private var alertInput = "Hello, world!"
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(alertInput)
            Text("Alert Message \(Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.triangle.fill"))")
            Button("Show alert", action: { isShowingAlert = true })
        }
        .padding()
        .alert("Alert message...", isPresented: $isShowingAlert) {
            TextField("", text: $alertInput) // Works in iOS16, but is ignored in iOS15
            Text("Alert Message \(Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.triangle.fill"))") // `Image` concatenation won't work
            Button("OK", action: { })
        }
    }
}
```